# postgresql statement prob

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two table A and B as following.

```
A:
key type
0    t
1    f
2    t
3    f
4    t
5    t
.......
B:
key   name
0     Mary
0     Tony
0     Krolik
1     Tom
2     Tony
3     Tony
3     Mary
3     Tom
4     Tony
4     Tim
5     Tim
5     Mary
5     Wuli
.....
```

I hope to find top n occurence name that it's type is 'f'.

For example, in A, the type of key 1 and 3 are 'f', we find key 1 and 3 in table B, there are 2 'Tom' and 1 'Mary' and 1 'Tony'.

```
    1     Tom
    3     Tony
    3     Mary
    3     Tom
```

if n = 1 and the table is just showed as before, we hope to get 'Tom', because its occurence is top 1.
How can I write sql statement to satisfy these requirement?
I write something like below, but it is wrong. Can anyone help me? I assume n = 20.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 20 name 
FROM B
WHERE key IN    (
SELECT key
FROM A
WHERE "type" = 'f'
) 
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to need aggregation.  And the equivalent of `top` in Postgres is `limit` or `fetch first <row> rows`:

```
SELECT name, key
FROM B
WHERE B.key IN (SELECT A.key
                FROM A
                WHERE "type" = 'f'
               ) 
ORDER BY key;
```

This corresponds to the results presented in the question.  Your description doesn't quite match those results.